# Can pony mode be used with django-html-mumamo-mode?

Tags: django, emacs, nxhtml

I'm just beginning to use Django and I want to use a mode which supports the framework. I browsed through the [django wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs) and found out that there are a lot of emacs modes for Django, which made it hard for me to decide which mode to use. Pony mode has a lot of features that makes the workflow easier, and django-html-mumamo-mode looks great for editing templates. I want to use the two modes but I do not know if the two will coexist perfectly. Also, template editing is included in Pony's feature list, but I do not know if that is enough (since templates may include snippets of different languages), which is why I'm considering using django-html-mumamo-mode along with pony. Can it be done? Any suggestions for working with django in emacs is also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried it, (I just found out about Pony Mode because of your question, it looks awesome) but I would guess that you would get weird behavior by default.

However, I'd bet that if you commented out lines [1138](https://github.com/davidmiller/pony-mode/blob/a3fc2e9983d18ce55a06e9b93973cb4cad5057d6/pony-mode.el#L1138) and the hook added on [1159](https://github.com/davidmiller/pony-mode/blob/a3fc2e9983d18ce55a06e9b93973cb4cad5057d6/pony-mode.el#L1159). (Of course, those lines will change as the master branch changes) pony-mode should play nice with django-html-mumamo-mode.

*Should*: I didn't find any references to `tpl` anywhere else in `pony-mode.el`, which is a ridiculously rough metric. But it also *looks* like pony-tpl-mode is only loaded in that file so that the author could add it as a hook to html-mode.